# Operation not permitted when accessing Downloads folder

Tags: terminal, permission, iterm, tmux

When I try to `ls` the `~/Downloads` folder on my mac I get a `ls: Downloads: Operation not permitted` error. My user does have rwx permissions on the folder. I can look at the folder just fine in finder. I use `tmux` in iterm2. The issue does not exist when I use `terminal.app`. It does work if I start `tmux` in `terminal.app`, regardless of which terminal emulator I use to control tmux. `iTerm.app` already has Downloads folder permissions in Security & Privacy settings. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by removing and re-adding the folder permissions for iTerm.app in the Security & Privacy dialogue.